# Restart container from inside

Tags: docker, centos

On a batch job, Am doing a large number of operations 
inside a docker.

Is there to send a command from inside so docker 
can come back as if it were just started ?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve / why you need this?

Comment: usually, my python app opens too many tcp ports, RAM allocation,.... Just want to reset from initial state.

Comment: My solution would be using signal to trigger the application reloads.

Comment: what if the application eats all dockerressources

Answer (score 14):

You just need to install docker client when building your docker images and map `/var/run/docker.sock` when running a new container to enable docker client inside the container to connect the docker daemon on the host, then you can use `docker` command just like on the host.

First, add commands to install docker-ce in your `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM centos:7.8.2003

ENV DOCKER_VERSION='19.03.8'

RUN set -ex \
    && DOCKER_FILENAME=https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/x86_64/docker-${DOCKER_VERSION}.tgz \
    && curl -L ${DOCKER_FILENAME} | tar -C /usr/bin/ -xzf - --strip-components 1 docker/docker
```

Then, build a new image and run a new container using it:

```
$ docker build --tag docker-in-docker:v1 .
$ docker run -dit \
             --name docker-in-docker \
             -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro \
             docker-in-docker:v1 bash
```

Now, you can operate docker-daemon (on the host) inside docker container.

```
$ docker exec -it docker-in-docker docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
bdc2d81b2227        docker-in-docker:v1   "bash"                   8 seconds ago       Up 7 seconds                            docker-in-docker
# just restart the container docker-in-docker in the container docker-in-docker:
$ docker exec docker-in-docker docker restart docker-in-docker
```

Comment: This approach will work, and can be appropriate in some circumstances. However, it will lose all the security isolation of the container, and essentially give it root access to the whole host (including access to anything, including containers, running on it).

Comment: Explain please, why docker client have write access to docker host with only read-only permissions on docker.sock?

Comment: @Mikl 
In most prod-environments you shouldn't do it. You expose a lot of information and probably with a bit of knowledge the attacker is still able to gain root access through it. Also an attacker could start new containers and use your machine for a bot-net ;) 
https://raesene.github.io/blog/2016/03/06/The-Dangers-Of-Docker.sock/

Answer (score -3):

reboot command works from withing container.
I use this in my Go code inside docker

```
out, err = exec.Command("reboot").Output()
```

Comment: This just kills the container. You'd have to use external scheduling to get it to actually come back