# Cannot reboot system from C++

Tags: c++, linux, docker

I've a C++ program running in a docker container. I want to reboot container via my program but I cannot.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM gcc

WORKDIR /client
COPY . .

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install qt5-qmake qtbase5-dev libmosquitto-dev -y

RUN qmake mainapp.pro && make
RUN chmod +x docker-entrypoint.sh
```

docker-entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
./mainapp -e
```

Here is my reboot function (cleared from unnecessary codes):

```
    Logger::getInstance()->write(QString("Sync"));
    sync();
    Logger::getInstance()->write(QString("Setuid"));
    setuid(0);
    Logger::getInstance()->write(QString("RB_AUTOBOOT"));
    reboot(RB_AUTOBOOT);
    Logger::getInstance()->write(QString("Reboot"));
    system("reboot");
```

I can see ALL the outputs and then it prints an error message. Here is the error message:

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
Failed to talk to init daemon.
```

I tried to reboot from container but it doesn't work as well:

```
root@93501f6d7fc8:/client# reboot
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
Failed to talk to init daemon.
root@93501f6d7fc8:/client# shutdown -r
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

I've searched this problem and tried most of the suggestions but they didn't solved my problem.

I am open to all your ideas and suggestions.

Comment: Running docker container is just a set of processes. What do you want to reboot in the set of processes?

Comment: Maybe you do not know what you want? Maybe you want to do something like  "docker restart my_container" or "exit" or such?

Comment: I want to reboot the whole container and run the app again.

Comment: I will not be able to run "docker restart container". Only access to this app will be with MQTT messages. I will send reboot message via MQTT and then it should restart itself.

Comment: There may be an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49713054/restart-container-from-inside (though it looks like it has some serious security concerns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answers. I added this to my docker compose yaml file:

```
    privileged: true
    restart: always
```

After that, `reboot(RB_AUTOBOOT);` rebooted my container and started the app successfully.

Comment: I'd expect that to reboot the whole host.  Is that what you actually want?

Comment: Yes. Without "privileged", I cannot even execute "reboot" or "shutdown" inside the container.

Answer (score 2):

`system("reboot")` tries to use the shell (which may not exist in your docker container) to run the `reboot` command (which may not exist in your docker container). Besides, "rebooting" is not a well-defined concept. You can't reboot the kernel, since that's shared. A docker container is an app-level container.

To restart your app, and by extension the container, just use `docker restart=always` and then call `std::exit(0)` to exit your app normally.